# I want my link labels to link to an image saved on my desktop?!?! Is This possible?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to link my labels to and image saved on my desktop???

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your href link attribute to a local url like:

```
href="file://localhost/c:/winnt/help/ciadmin.htm"
```

Or this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644690%28VS.85%29.aspx) example

Anyway I think you should consider why are you doing such thing. please give a glance to this [article](http://www.mcli.dist.maricopa.edu/tut/tut8a.html) first

Comment: these methods work for a webpage...but i dont believe they work for a windows form application...

Comment: Hi JB, which window forms component are you using specifically?